# Android widget Intent without layout

Tags: android, web-services, android-intent, widget, android-widget

is it possible to make an Intent whic runs in background? Like a service i assume.

I need to perform an action (call webservice) when the user clicks on a widget.

My code below

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.putExtra("webServiceId", mWSId);
PendingIntent pending = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,intent, 0);
views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.btnWidgetToggle, pending);
appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(mAppWidgetId, views);

Intent resultValue = new Intent();
resultValue.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID,
        mAppWidgetId);
setResult(RESULT_OK, resultValue);

finish();
```

Should I make my intent to perform an action to a service or something like that? 
Thanks!

UPDATE:
Im trying to do it by calling an IntentService now, but it doesnt calls it. My code below:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, widgetService.class);
intent.putExtra("webServiceId",mWSId);
PendingIntent pending = PendingIntent.getService(context, 0, intent, 0);
views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.btnWidgetToggle, pending);
```

any idea?

Comment: Yes, start a service. I would recommend an `IntentService`.

Comment: @Karakuri thanks for the confirmation. Do you know how to implement it? I updated the code above with what im trying by the time...

Comment: Did you register the service in your `AndroidManifest.xml`?

Comment: @Karakuri: ups! It was that!!!! Thanksss

Answer (score 0):

- I am not sure what you are trying to achieve
- I am right you want to call a widget on click of a `widget(view)`

---

- This can be achieved in a simple way by calling the `onClick` action
  of a widget and place the `web-service` invocation code inside the
  `onCllickListener`

***Sample***

```
button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
              //Place your webservice invocation code here
}}
```

---

*If you want to use service in some way have a look at [android documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html) on how to use it*

***Hope this helps !***

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by calling a IntentService.

Here is my code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, widgetService.class);
intent.putExtra("webServiceId",mWSId);
PendingIntent pending = PendingIntent.getService(context, 0, intent, 0);
views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.btnWidgetToggle, pending);
```

Thanks @Karakuri